# Background image with :before and :after

Tags: css, background-image, pseudo-element

I have a row on responsive website that I would like to have the attached image as a background image on top and below. I know this can be achieved with the pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`, but I am not sure how to do this.
I have the row:

```
.row {
    background: #444444;
}
```

so how could I apply the image before and after?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9h3w2qqvxqntps/background.svg?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

use `:before` and `:after` for `background-image` in this way -

```
.row:before {
content: url('imageURL');
}
.row:after {
content: url('imageURL');
}
```

now you can position each `:before` and `:after` with `position: absolute` and then adjust `top` and `bottom` properties.